# Can I Change Ad unit id of live android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, admob

I have problem with admob ad unit id for android app. Suppose I have live android app(Version 1)  from admob account 1 which contains live admob ads and Now i want to replace ad unit id with the same live application(Version 2) which is created from admob account 2 . So it is eligible for admob account or live app ? OR there is restrictions over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can replace your ad units without issues. 
The only problem is that until all the users update to the latest version of your app, the ones that didn't update yet, are going to still be using the older ad unit. So you are going to have your earnings splited for a while between your two admob accounts.
To prevent this, you should consider using a mediation manager like MoPub, so you make your app ad-unit independent.

Comment: Thanks @ale.m  will it close my play store account if i change ad unit id to my live app? from different account

Comment: No one is going to close your play store account. You will have change your ad unit and you will also need to update your google-services.json.

Comment: @DharmeshDhameliya , confirm this answer if it was helpful. This is a good practise in this forum.